# (click)='' event is not working , in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, click

I explored a lot but solution is not working for me.
I am trying to call a method in my code but it is not working. There is no Error occurring but click event is not working also.
In my code, I am adding a button dynamically and it is added in my code. But when I am clicking on `Approved`  or `UnApproved` then nothing is happening. I am using `<ng-table>` , `Approved` and `UnApproved` button are in `<ng-table>` directive.
Please suggest me where I am doing wrong?

My code is:

```
     editData() {
    this.data.forEach(function (row) {
          if (row.isApproved) {
        row.editButton = "<button (click)='approveUnApproveLeave()'>UnApproved</button>";
      } else {
        row.editButton = "<button (click)='approveUnApproveLeave()'>Approved</button>";
        row.isApproved = row.isApproved.toString();
      }
    })
  }

  approveUnApproveLeave() {
    console.log("approveUnApproveLeave called");
  }

} // class closed
```

please see the snapshot for better understanding.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **`innterHTML`** to display dynamic HTML then...

When you are adding html dynamically using **`innerHTML`** it will work fine and give you desire output in UI front. But with same approach, If dynamic HTML contains any **`angular context`** in it `eg. (click) event`, **`angular context`** will not work because **`innerHTML`** is not meant for it.

So when dynamic HTML contains angular context in it, you must think of using [DynamicComponentLoader](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-component-loader.html#!#sts=Resolving%20Components) which injects component along with HTML dynamically where you can use angular context `eg. click event`

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/BcQXNf5AWrDUXFamIGIy?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Angular processes component templates when it compiles a component (with AoT before the browser loads the application). HTML added afterwards isn't processed by Angular. `(click)="..."` is added as-is and then ignored by Angular.

What you can do is register an event handler imperatively

```
  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef);

  editData() {
    this.data.forEach((row) => { // don't use function if you want to use `this`
          if (row.isApproved) {
        row.editButton = "<button>UnApproved</button>";
      } else {
        row.editButton = "<button>Approved</button>";
        row.isApproved = row.isApproved.toString();
      }
    });
    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); // to ensure the DOM is updated
    // add event handlers imperatively
    this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(button).forEach(b => b.addEventListener('click', this.eventHandler.bind(this));
  }
```

Comment: Thank You, But I got  error after doing this:Error: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more code. Can you create a minimal reproduction in Plunker?

Comment: what will be the right solution ? any One please share

Comment: Did any one find the solution. This didn't work for me.

Comment: I forgot to remove the `(click)='approveUnApproveLeave()'` from the code I copied from the answer. I guess this is what the downvotes were fore. I fixed that in my answer.